# Jquery load - replacement of a div

Tags: jquery, html

Probably there is just some formating problem ... I already checked different examples from stackoverflow .. however I still have no idea why the "load" does not work for me. Here the two files:

File1(index.html):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Load remote content into object element</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="siteloader"></div>​
        <script>
            $('#siteloader').load('test.html #content2');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

File2(test.html):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <div id="content1"><p>Some content1</p></div>​
    <div id="content2"><p>Some content2</p></div>​
    <div id="content3"><p>Some content3</p></div>​
</html>
```

Both files are located in the same folder. If I open index.html with a browser (Iceweasel(Firefox) or Epiphany), I only get a white page.
I am working on a Debian (kernel: 2.6.32-5-amd64), if that should matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector string isn't right. It has too many quotes. Also, I'd put your code in a `$(document).ready()` callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#siteloader').load('test.html #content2');
});
```

Also, jQuery is on version 1.9.1. I would consider updating.

Also, try giving your `test.html` file a `<body>` tag.

Comment: They must have edited their question, because I'm not seeing the 'too many quotes' you're talking about.

Comment: I replaced  $('#siteloader').load('test.html #content2'); with your code, and I use jQuery 1.9.1 now. ... however it still does not work.

Comment: @Alex: Open up you JS console and see what's wrong

Comment: Do I maybe need to install something at the OS regarding jQuery ?

Comment: @Alex: Have you given your second HTML file a `<body>` tag?

Comment: @Alex Javascript is not Flash.

Comment: I just added body-tags in test.html .. does not help either. ... currently searching for this JS-console

Comment: Hah, now it works in iceweasel !! ... seems like I tested all the time in Epiphany, where it still does not work. The initial problem were the "''", but as well the <body> tag is needed, otherwise the whole file is included. Thanks all!

Comment: Seems like the $(document).ready(function() { .. }); is not implicitly needed ... however according to the jquery doku, it seems like I should have it in the code.